# Counter won't work to end loop

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment and it is working well so far.  But several aspects aren't working.  For starters, my counters for int total and int counter won't work.  Also my if statements don't seem to be working.  I have been scratching my head for several days now.

The assignment calls for a program to input the order number and will loop based on how many orders the customer has. It also calls for customer name, sign type(wood or plastic), the number of characters,and color of characters.

Some more information:

- The base price for all signs is $20.
- If sign is wood, add $10.  If it is plastic add $5.
- The first 5 letters/numbers are included in base price, and $2 for each additional character.
- Black or white characters are included in base price, there is an additional $8 for colored    letters.
- If the total charge is more than $100 give 25% discount on total price.

Here is my code right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Carpenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int orderNumber;
        String custName;
        String signType;
        int numOfCharacters;
        String color;
        int i = 20;
        double total;
        int counter;

        System.out.println("Enter your order number");

        orderNumber = sc.nextInt();

        counter=orderNumber;

        counter--;

        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter customer name");

        custName = sc.next();

        do{
            System.out.println("Enter the sign type (wood or plastic)");
            signType = sc.next();
            if(signType == "wood") {
                i+=10;
            }

            if(signType == "plastic") {
                i+=5;
            }

            System.out.println("Enter the number of characters");

            numOfCharacters = sc.nextInt();


            if(numOfCharacters > 5) {
                i += 2*(numOfCharacters-5);
            }

            System.out.println("Enter the color of characters");
            color = sc.next();

            if(color != "white" || color != "black") {
                i += 8;
            }

            total=  i;
            System.out.println("Total is: $" + total);
            if( total > 100 ) {
                total = (total * 0.25);
                System.out.println("The total is " + total );
            }
        }
        while(counter <= orderNumber);

    }

}
```

Comment: `...several aspects aren't working...` -- Please be more specific.  What about your program is not working?

Comment: Please learn how to debug your code (or understand what debugging is). This is one good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html or this if you don't use eclipse: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077445/testing-debugging/debug-with-jdb.html

Comment: You shouldn't compare Strings with `==` and `!=`, because this will onyly check object identity. Use `.equals` instead.

Comment: If you point out the specific behavior you are seeking which is not currently manifesting, that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: My counter for the amount of orders will not work

Comment: @confused We gathered that; merlin2011 is saying that you need to say *exactly how it doesn't work*. What is it doing? What do you want it to do? If you're able to at least describe exactly what the wrong behavior is, that's already a very good step towards finding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added comments to guide you through the changes I made. Also, remember to call the sc.NextLine() function after you get user input so that they can input something different next time (this is called 'flushing' the buffer).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Carpenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int orderNumber;
        String custName;
        String signType;
        int numOfCharacters;
        String color;
        int i = 20;
        double total;
        int counter;

//I changed the phrasing just because it is a little confusing
        System.out.println("Enter your number of orders");

        orderNumber = sc.nextInt();

        counter = orderNumber;

        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter customer name");

        custName = sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();
//When you know how many times you want to repeat something (like when a user tells you how many) I prefer using a for-loop, a do while loop works as well though
        for(int x=0; x<counter;x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the sign type (wood or plastic)");
            signType = sc.next();
//When comparing Strings, there is a function that you can use to compare them rather than using '=='          
// It is also good to use the 'equalsIgnoreCase()' function to be more user friendly and robust         

            if(signType.equalsIgnoreCase("wood")) {
                i+=10;
            }

            if(signType.equalsIgnoreCase("plastic")) {
                i+=5;
            }

//Flush the buffer (I haven't tested if this is necessary or not, it is good practice though)            
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of characters");

            numOfCharacters = sc.nextInt();


            if(numOfCharacters > 5) {
                i += 2*(numOfCharacters-5);
            }

            System.out.println("Enter the color of characters");
            color = sc.next();

//Same concept as above, the differene is the ! before the function to test if it is false or not
            if(!color.equalsIgnoreCase("white") || !color.equalsIgnoreCase("black")) {
                i += 8;
            }
        }
            total =  i;
//You will not want to print this out until the end due to the possibility of it being over $100            
//          System.out.println("Total is: $" + total);
            if( total > 100 ) {
//Mathematically speaking, you are making your total a quarter of what the original is, rather than taking a quarter off. You want 75% rather than 25%
               // total = (total * 0.25);
                total = (total * 0.75);               
            }
            System.out.println("Total is: $" + total);
        }




}
```

Comment: You are my hero. Godspeed...

Answer (score 1):

You should set `counter` to the correct starting value (which is presumably 1 in your case):

```
    orderNumber = sc.nextInt();
    counter=1;
   //counter=orderNumber;
   //counter--;
```

Then at the end of the loop, you should increment your `counter`:

```
do{
    //code
    counter++;
}
while(counter <= orderNumber);
```